# Selenium clicking buttons by traversing through parent node

Tags: python, selenium, button, xpath

Need to exercise buttons ( edit / delete) in following HTML. Unique between all devices are "device-name". Hence locating target device is straight as -

```
cmd = "//div[@class='device-name' and text()='%s']" % (devicename)
element = brHandle.find_elements_by_xpath(cmd)
```

HTML -

```
<div class="device" id="device-1">..</div>
<div class="device" id="device-2">..</div>
    <div class="device-form-factor desktop">
        <div class="device-platform unknown"></div>
        <div class="device-status">
            ....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-name">auto-generated</div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="button edit" href="#">Edit</div>&nbsp;
            <div class="button delete" href="#">Delete</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="device" id="device-3">..</div>
```

....

To access parent and then button, i tried following- but didn't work out. I was expecting to fetch device-id and then form my xpath to edit/delete button. Please suggest -

```
parent = element.find_element_by_xpath("..").text()
```

Comment: what about `element[0].find_element_by_xpath("..")`

Comment: @eLRull : Thanks for pointing out , i was finding for elements without expecting a list.

Comment: np, did it work?

Comment: parent = element.find_element_by_xpath("..")
dev_id = parent.get_attribute("id")  ---> got me id. I used parent element and css to access delete button. It was not able to find the constructed xpath with dev_id